# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint128"

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I am compiling using sol 0.8.0 and the following line is producing the error in the title:

```
uint256 public constant MASK = uint128(~0);
```

Error:

```
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint128".
```

When changing the variable to this:

```
uint256 public constant MASK = ~0;
```

The error changes to:

```
Type int_const -1 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. Cannot implicitly convert signed literal to unsigned type.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changed it to this:

```
uint256 public constant MASK = type(uint128).max;
```

[New restrictions in 0.8.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/breaking/080-breaking-changes.html#new-restrictions)

Answer (score 4):

From solidity `>0.8.0`.

Explicit conversions between literals and an integer type `T` are only allowed if the literal lies between `type(T).min` and `type(T).max`. In particular, replace usages of `uint(-1)` with `type(uint).max`.

Comment: OP reefers to type(uint128).max, while type(uint).max is shortcut for type(uint256).max